# Transform csv data - continuous to discrete steps

Tags: perl, csv, transformation

I have a list of some jobs (or whatever items/action) and their start and end date.
Now for each minute of the day, I need to know how many jobs were active.

So the input looks like this:
(actually I get it directly as CSV)

```
Jobname |        Start        |         End          
---------------------------------------------------      
JobA    | 04/10/2015 08:00:00 | 04/10/2015 09:00:00
JobB    | 04/10/2015 10:00:00 | 04/10/2015 10:00:59
JobC    | 04/10/2015 10:00:00 | 04/10/2015 11:00:00
```

The output shall look like this:

**Note**: Jobnames just added for clearity, in the real output I am only interested in the number of active jobs per minute, not which jobs were active

```
Time                | Number of active jobs
---------------------------------------------------      
04/10/2015 00:00:00 | 0
[..]
04/10/2015 08:00:00 | 1 (JobA)
04/10/2015 08:01:00 | 1 (JobA)
[..]
04/10/2015 09:00:00 | 1 (JobA)
04/10/2015 09:01:00 | 0
[..]
04/10/2015 09:59:00 | 0
04/10/2015 10:00:00 | 2 (JobB, JobC)
04/10/2015 10:01:00 | 1 (JobC)
[..]
04/10/2015 11:00:00 | 1 (JobC)
04/10/2015 11:01:00 | 0
[..]
04/10/2015 23:59:00 | 0
```

How can this be realized using Perl? Plase note that CPAN is not available and therefore unfortunately not an option. Thanks for any hint on this!

Comment: I would probably use a function to convert the times to seconds or minutes, and one for opposite. Which would exist on cpan already, so instead of potentially introducing bugs I would use that, e.g. DateTime, Time::Local. 
Then I would parse the dates given, put their converted values in a hash, then for each minute, remove jobs whose end time is past from that hash, and print all whose begin time is <= current minute ( or, if job names do not matter, just grep all whose begin time is <= current and print that number).

Comment: You will get better answers if you attempt to solve the problem yourself first. I will point out `Time::Piece` is a core module.

Answer (score 0):

How you need to approach this would be:

- Parse your input file. `Text::CSV` is one option, but using `split` on the delimiters of your lines will work as a stopgap.
- use `Time::Piece` and `strptime` to convert your start/stop times to something you can compare numerically. (`epoch`).
- store these in a data structure. If job name is unique, a `hash` is probably the tool for the job.
- calculate the start and end of your time slots (also in `epoch`). `Time::Piece` can do this for you too.
- Look for elements in the hash that have `start` and `end` that fall within the time window. `grep` can do this for you.

Note - if you don't have `CPAN` `Text::CSV` probably won't be available. `Time::Piece` should be, because it's core as of 5.9.5. Otherwise you *might* find you can use the `date` command to replicate the functionality.